# Symfony 3.3 Insert user info into table along form data

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an entity "brand" as follows

- id
- name
- user_id

I want to insert current logged in user id into this brand table, my controller code is as follows, id and name are working fine and being inserted into the table, please tell me what should I add to insert current user id into the db table, user can have many brands.

```
public function newBrandAction(Request $request)
{
    $brand = new brand();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($brand)
    ->add('name',TextType::class,array('label'=>'Brand Name'))
    ->add('save',SubmitType::class, array('label'=>'Add Brand'))
    ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($brand);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->render('coreBundle:layouts:newBrand.html.twig',
            array('form'=>$form->createView(),));
    }

    return $this->render('coreBundle:layouts:newBrand.html.twig',
        array('form'=>$form->createView(),));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to actually insert user_id into database table without showing any options on the form, I have done this in the following manner.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
        $em->persist($brand);
        $brand->setUserId($user);
        $em->flush();
/* */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add user relation like this inside your form:

```
    ->add('user', EntityType::class, array(
         'class' => 'YourBundle:User',
         'choice_label' => 'username' //here you can insert what field you want or you can remove this option
    ))
```

Obviously you need to add `EntityType` to the `use` of your controller

I advise you to read this link:

[Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

To only insert the current user you can do this before persist

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
$brand->setUser($user);
```

Comment: I have read the link, but I do not want to give option on the form, I just want to insert the current logged in user, may something to add after the isValid() check?

Answer (score 0):

Use StofDoctrineExtensions Bundle

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;


 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @Gedmo\Blameable(on="create")
 */
private $creator;
```